# Override a plugin class function

Tags: functions

I have something similar as [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/282960/25187).

In a third party plugin class we have a function that I want to override by extending that class.

The original class function:

```
class Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook {
    public function get_location( $facebook_event ) {

        if ( !isset( $facebook_event->place->id ) ) {
            return null;
        }
        //other code here
}
```

What I tried, but this didn't work (no effect):

```
class Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook_Ext extends Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook {
    public function get_location( $facebook_event ) {

        if ( !isset( $facebook_event->place->id ) ) {
            $facebook_event->place->id = ''; //added this line
            //return null;
        }
        //other code here
}

new Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook_Ext();
```

**What's wrong here? How can I get the desired effect?**

The original `Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook()` class is instantiated from another class:

```
class Import_Facebook_Events{

    private static $instance;

    public static function instance() {
        if( ! isset( self::$instance ) && ! (self::$instance instanceof Import_Facebook_Events ) ) {
            self::$instance = new Import_Facebook_Events;

            self::$instance->facebook = new Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook();

        }
        return self::$instance; 
    }
}
```

And the above class is instantiated from a separate function:

```
function run_import_facebook_events() {
    return Import_Facebook_Events::instance();
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could try to override the instance after the fact. eg. `Import_Facebook_Events::$instance = Import_Facebook_Events_Ext::instance();` ... otherwise you'd have to keep going back to what runs `run_import_facebook_events` to see if you can override at that top level.

Comment: @majick I tried that and I got a `This page isn’t working. infopsi.md is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500` screen.

Comment: before to instanciate your new class, you have to stop the instanciation of the original class then you have to find where this appends.

Comment: @mmm I added an answer, can you look at it?

Comment: @majick I added an answer, can you look at it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to solve my problem:

```
class Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook_Ext extends Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook {

    function get_location( $facebook_event ) {

        if ( !isset( $facebook_event->place->id ) ) {
            $facebook_event->place->id = '';
            //return null;
        }
        //other code here

        return $event_location;
    }
}

$new_ife_events = run_import_facebook_events();
$new_ife_events->facebook = new Import_Facebook_Events_Facebook_Ext();
```

**A question: the last two code lines must be included in a function/action?**

Comment: good solve, looks like you could use that wherever you need to... it really just depends where you actually want to use `$new_ife_events`